# Java error "cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, gui, исключения

Мой код:

```
package buttonProject;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGUI1B implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleGUI1B gui = new SimpleGUI1B();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton button = new JButton("click me");

        button.addActionListener(this);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        button.setText("I've been clicked");
    }}
```

В ответ:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>           button cannot be resolved

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как устранить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас button описана как переменная внутри метода go(). Из метода actionPerformed она не видна. Советую прочитать про [области видимости](http://kulibaba.net/programming/java/lesson4). В данном случае переменная button находится в **локальной**  области метода go().

Для решения проблемы необходимо вынести переменную в поля класса.

```
public class SimpleGUI1B implements ActionListener {

    public JButton button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleGUI1B gui = new SimpleGUI1B();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        button = new JButton("click me");

        button.addActionListener(this);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        button.setText("I've been clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена и я воспользуюсь вашим советом.